# Outlook Notify v2 API - Create calendar subscription

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am setting up a subscription request. I receive the `validationtoken` url param so according to the docs I have to reply in the next five seconds doing this:

- Set the content type in the response header to `text\plain`.
- Include only the validation token in the response body.
- Return an HTTP `200` response code.

This tells the Outlook notifications service that the listener received the URL validation request, and the validation succeeded.

I am receiving an error though:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidParameter","message":"Notification URL 'https://mycallbackurl.com/api/notify?validationtoken=NTk4NzliNzktNTE1MS00ZjE1LWJjNzctMTE4NzI4NTNhODlh' verification failed 'System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataPushSubscriptionCallbackUrlValidationHelper.SendRequestAndVerifyResponse(Uri callbackUrl, PushSubscription pushSubscription)'."}
```

---

This is my reply that attempts to use that validation token:

**REQUEST**

```
https://mycallbackurl.com/api/notify?validationtoken=NTk4NzliNzktNTE1MS00ZjE1LWJjNzctMTE4NzI4NTNhODlh
```

**RESPONSE CODE**

```
200
```

**RESPONSE BODY**

```
NTk4NzliNzktNTE1MS00ZjE1LWJjNzctMTE4NzI4NTNhODlh
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS**

```
Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 09:42:50 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Accept, Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Api-Version
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PATCH, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Allow: POST, PATCH, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Api-Version: 1.3
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 48
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The only think that changes between what is expected for and what I am providing is content type:

- Expected: `text/plain`
- Produced: `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Assuming this is the reason of the error, would not make sense to allow both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a failure to establish a secure connection (SSL). There may be a problem with your SSL certificate. Is it a self-issued cert perhaps?